# converting ordered dict in python to normal dict and extract values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I have a csv file with latitudes and longitudes.

```
-37.8994,144.9799
-37.8063,144.9964
-37.8901,144.8885
```

I have python script which coverts these values from geocodes to locations.

```
import csv
import reverse_geocoder as rg 

with open('bb.csv', "rt", encoding='ascii') as infile:
    read = csv.reader(infile)
    for row in read :
        result = rg.search(row)
        print(type(result[0]))
        print(result)
```

output from the script

```
Loading formatted geocoded file...
<class 'collections.OrderedDict'>
[OrderedDict([('lat', '-37.88214'), ('lon', '144.98215'), ('name', 'Elwood'), ('admin1', 'Victoria'), ('admin2', 'Port Phillip'), ('cc', 'AU')])]
<class 'collections.OrderedDict'>
[OrderedDict([('lat', '-37.8'), ('lon', '145'), ('name', 'Abbotsford'), ('admin1', 'Victoria'), ('admin2', ''), ('cc', 'AU')])]
<class 'collections.OrderedDict'>
[OrderedDict([('lat', '-37.857'), ('lon', '144.89769'), ('name', 'Williamstown'), ('admin1', 'Victoria'), ('admin2', 'Hobsons Bay'), ('cc', 'AU')])]
```

I am struggling to extract out the values for keys -- name, admin1, admin2 and cc.

essentially I want to convert the lat, long values in csv file to their location values and paste those values back to the CSV. Please can someone help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confused by Python's print representation of these dictionaries. Whether they are ordered or not is not at all the problem here, it's just that you are not printing what you say you want to print.

```py
    for row in read:
        result = rg.search(row)
        print(type(result[0]))
        for item in result:
            print(",".join("'%s': '%s'" % (k,v) for k, v in item.items()))
            # or maybe
            print(",".join([item['lat'], item['lon']]))
```

This is similar to how `print(print)` just prints a *representation* of Python's `print` function, not its actual contents (which would be quite useless to a normal human reader anyway).

Comment: I had tried item.lat or item.name, but I had to use item['lat'] instead, thanks a ton @tripleee

Answer (score 1):

It's easy, you can do `json.dumps()` (direct `dict()` to be avoided, because of unordered):

```
import csv
import reverse_geocoder as rg 
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

with open('bb.csv', "rt", encoding='ascii') as infile:
    read = csv.reader(infile)
    for row in read :
        result = rg.search(row)
        dicres = json.loads(json.dumps(OrderedDict(result)))
```

Now `dicres` is your dict.